# I got these error messages when trying to unmount /dev/sda3

Tags: server, umount

I got these error messages when trying to unmount `/dev/sda3`.

```
root@marudhu:~# umount -t /dev/sda3
umount: bad usage
Try 'umount --help' for more information.
root@marudhu:~# umount -t/dev/sda3
umount: bad usage
Try 'umount --help' for more information.
root@marudhu:~#
```

Comment: https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/umount.8.html

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add some information about what you are trying to do. Don't post screenshots of text, copy and paste it into your question. The title of your post seems unrelated to the screenshot.

Comment: @OrganicMarble I fixed the question's title and converted the screen photo into plain text.

Answer (score 2):

From `man umount` :

```
-t, --types type...
              Indicate that the actions should only be taken on filesystems of
              the  specified  type.
```

You haven't specified a filesystem after the `-t` flag. Use the following command that doesn't have  the optional `-t` flag in it. Also you don't need to be root user to run the following command if you preface the same command with `sudo` instead as follows:

```
sudo umount /dev/sda3
```